# AWS CloudWatch - Log group does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm getting this error message when trying to see the log file in AWS CloudWatch for my AWS Lambda function.

```
An error occurred while describing log streams.
The specified log group does not exist.

Log group does not exist
The specific log group: /aws/lambda/xxxxx does not exist in this account or region.
```

By the way, I'm using the Singapore region.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, **chatty material and abbreviated txtspk**, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: Hi Mohammad Nurdin. Please check the answer and mark the question as answered if it so. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that your Lambda function's execution role has sufficient permissions to write logs to CloudWatch, and that the log group resource in the IAM policy includes your function's name.

In the IAM console, review and edit the IAM policy for the execution role to make sure that:

- The write actions CreateLogGroup and CreateLogStream are allowed. You should attach these policies in the IAM roles of the Lambda function

Note: If you don't need custom permissions for your function, you can attach the managed policy AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole, which allows Lambda to write logs to CloudWatch.

- The AWS Region specified in the Amazon Resource Name (ARN) is the
  same as your Lambda function's Region.
- The log-group resource includes your Lambda function name. For
  example, if your function is named myLambdaFunction, the log-group is
  /aws/lambda/myLambdaFunction.

Here is an example of the permissions in the JSON format

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:region:accountId:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                " arn:aws:logs:region:accountId:log-group:/aws/lambda/functionName:*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```